# SEO best practices for domains in multiple languages

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, language, best-practices

I have a domain https://www.understandmydreams.com (online dream interpreter) and I wish to expand the service to more languages.

The content will be different in each language, not just simple translation, since people will input different dreams in each language.

What should be my best practice in terms of SEO?

1. Use folder, e.g.: https://understandmydreams.com/es for Spanish
2. Use subdomain, e.g. https://he.understandmydreams.com for Hebrew (I have made this already)
3. Buy a totally different domain like https://www.understandmydreams.co.ar (the problem here is there are many different countries speaking Spanish and it's a general domain not country specific - but it might be better for SEO like that)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach here would be using folders(approach 1) to implement this on your site(this is done by many companies).

One of the problems with the subdomain approach is that the Domain Authority of the primary domain is not forwarded to the sub-domains so you would lose a lot of SEO benefits that your domain might have gained over time.

And if you go by the third approach it will also have the same problem of not getting the SEO benefits on top of being very costly to purchase and maintain multiple domains.